# AngularJS - Manage the $http success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I want to change my service `myFct` but I have a problem:

> This is my current service which works well

Factory

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('myFct', myFct);

function myFct(){
    return{
        getMyData : function() {
            return $http.get('./my/data.json');
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
app.module('MyApp')
.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.$inject = ['myFct'];

function myCtrl(myFct){
    vm = this;
    vm.myData = myData();

    function myData(){
        myFct.getMyData().success(function(data){
            vm.myData = data;
        });
    }
}
```

> I want to manage the $http success in my factory, for example

Factory

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('myFct', myFct);

function myFct(){
    return{
        getMyData : function() {
            return $http.get('./my/data.json').success(function(data){
                return data;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
app.module('MyApp')
.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

myCtrl.$inject = ['myFct'];

function myCtrl(myFct){
    vm = this;
    vm.myData = myFct.getMyData();
}
```

The result of variable `vm.myData` is undefined. I am aware that the service $http is asynchronous, but how can I handle it in such a way that the variable `vm.myData` is equal to the data of the my json file?

Comment: can't return from `success`, use `then` or `success` in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement behaviour similar to what you're after using a function callback style.

In your factory:

```
function myFct() {
    return{
        getMyData : function(callback) {
            return $http.get('./my/data.json').success(function(data){
                callback(data)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
function myCtrl(myFct){
    vm = this;
    myFct.getMyData(function(data) {
        vm.myData = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something on the line of this:

```
function myFct(){
return{
    getMyData : function() {
        return $http.get('./my/data.json').then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var somethingElse = {newData:data};
            return somethingElse;
        });
    }
}}
```

And then something like this in the controller (sorry, haven't touched angular for like half a year, so double check semantics):

```
  function myData(){
    myFct.getMyData().then(function(data){
       $scope.myData = data;
       console.log($scope.myData);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is no different at all from the way that he's doing it right now other than introducing a new variable which is an unnecessary allocation.

Comment: It is completely different as "success" does not generate a separate promise unlike "then".

Comment: Why bother creating somethingElse instead of just returning data?

Comment: You do not need to create somethingElse. That was not the point of my answer whatsoever. The only reason I suggest doing that is to make sure that promises work accordingly, meaning that it allows manipulation of data in between the request to JSON file and the variable assignment. 

For testing purposes purely as I have no ability to run the test at the moment myself.